# If $p$ is prime and congruent to $1$, then show $((\frac{p-1}{2})!)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I got another one.

Quadratic residues are completely new to me...

Thanks!

Comment: If $p$ is a prime and congruent to 1 modulo what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the congruences, $p-1 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, $\text{ }\text{ } p-2 \equiv -2 \pmod p$
and so on upto, $\frac{p+1}2 \equiv -\frac{p-1}2 \pmod p$.

Multiplying and rearranging, $$(p-1)!\equiv 1\cdot (-1)\cdot 2 \cdot (-2) ...\frac{p-1}2 \cdot (-\frac{p-1}2) \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}[(\frac{p-1}{2})!]^2 \pmod p$$

Thus, by Wilson's theorem, $ -1 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}[(\frac{p-1}{2})!]^2 \pmod p$.

If by "$p$ is congruent to $1$", you meant that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we are done as $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2} =1$.

Comment: Damn. You're good.  How long did I take you to get so proficient at number theory?

Comment: @Bliebervik Heh .. I am not really good at number theory, to be honest I remembered that I saw this when as an application of Wilson's theorem recently, so it didn't take me long to recollect and write :)

Comment: Number theory.... So many rules! Taking this course in second year college, and I'm getting my butt kicked pretty good. I'm doing well, but that's due to 20 hour weekend study marathons.

Comment: @Bliebervik Don't know, I have only started studying elementary things on my own :D .. anyway, you should accept answers if you are satisfied with it :)